# Why the input name is not changing its value?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to edit the user profile data, and when I change the name in the input field, it won't change, it keeps the name that the user has.

```
 const [nameInput, setNameInput] = useState('');


  const editUserData = () => {
    const userParams = {
      phone: phone,
      fullName: nameInput,
      gender: value,
      birthdate: date,
    };
    axios
      .put('url', userParams)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response', response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };

  <TextInput
      style={styles.nameInputStyle}
      onChangeText={(event) => setNameInput(event)}
      value={nameInput}
      keyboardType="email-address"
      returnKeyType="done"
      onEndEditing={(e) => handleValidName(e.nativeEvent.text)}
      autoCapitalize="sentences"
   />
```

How can I change the value name in the input field?

Comment: It's ```setNameInput(event.taget.value)```, because you want to get the value of the textfield, not the event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set it to `event.target.value`, not `event`:

```js
<TextInput
      style={styles.nameInputStyle}
      onChangeText={(event) => setNameInput(event.target.value)}
      value={nameInput}
      keyboardType="email-address"
      returnKeyType="done"
      onEndEditing={(e) => handleValidName(e.nativeEvent.text)}
      autoCapitalize="sentences"
/>
```

**EDIT**

`event.target.value` won't work. Use this instead:

```js
<TextInput
      style={styles.nameInputStyle}
      onChangeText={setNameInput}
      value={nameInput}
      keyboardType="email-address"
      returnKeyType="done"
      onEndEditing={(e) => handleValidName(e.nativeEvent.text)}
      autoCapitalize="sentences"
/>
```

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.target.value'), this error is shown in my console

Comment: @Martina I added an edit